# Copy an value ( value is an object ) from an object to array is not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, deep-copy

I have variables like this

```
    var rough = {
        JOHN : {
          date: "03-03-2021",
          name: "JOHN",
          Qty: 123,
          unit: "g"
        },
SEBASTIAN : {
          date: "03-03-2021",
          name: "SEBASTIAN",
          Qty: 456,
          unit: "g"
        }}
```

I want to change its format to

```
var lastyear = {
      data: [
        {
          date: "03-03-2021",
          name: "JOHN",
          Qty: 123,
          unit: "g"
        },{
          date: "03-03-2021",
          name: "SEBASTIAN",
          Qty: 456,
          unit: "g"
        }]
```

But I want to copy the value to change the format.

Comment: Sorry this is working fine the issue was with my express return. This is my first question and its question and solution is working properly shall I delete this question. Or this comment is enough

Answer (score 2):

Quick way is by using `Object.values` (`{ data: Object.values(rough) }`)

```js
var rough = {
  JOHN: {
    date: "03-03-2021",
    name: "JOHN",
    Qty: 123,
    unit: "g",
  },
  SEBASTIAN: {
    date: "03-03-2021",
    name: "SEBASTIAN",
    Qty: 456,
    unit: "g",
  },
};

lastyear = { data: Object.values(rough) };

console.log(lastyear)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` with `Object.entries`:

```js
const rough = { JOHN : { date: "03-03-2021", name: "JOHN", Qty: 123, unit: "g" },SEBASTIAN : { date: "03-03-2021", name: "SEBASTIAN", Qty: 456, unit: "g" }}

const result = Object.entries(rough).reduce((a,[name, value])=>[...a,{...value,name}],[]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your time, but the solution I used itself is working. I just apologise for wasting your time

Answer (score 1):

And I used for..in

```
var keys = Object.keys(rough);
    for (const data in rough){
      lastyear.data.push(rough[data]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just copied by value to array.

```
var keys = Object.keys(rough);
keys.forEach((data) => {
lastyear.data.push(Object.assign({}, rough[data]));
}
```